# AspectJ how to trace anonymous interface or class implementation

Tags: aop, aspectj

Lets say I have the following code:

```
package util;
interface Function {
    public void call(Object... args);
}

OR

package util;
class Function {
    public void call(Object... args){};
}
```

And this is how I use said interface or class:

```
Function onComplete = new Function() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I want to do with aspectj is trace the "new Function" -- but it does not work

```
@AfterReturning("call(util.Function.new())")
```

This Pointcut above does not work.

Any help or insights would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sure.

This is the answer.

```
@AfterReturning("call(util.Function+.new())")
```

The "+" indicates to match any sub-classes of Function as well as Function itself.

Where as

```
@AfterReturning("call(util.Function.new())")
```

Is strictly going to match Function class only.

That is my understanding from reading the docs.